# How to see all lines of code I've added to a codebase?

Tags: git

I want to see all the lines of code that I've added to a codebase because I want to run a character frequency count. I'd like something like `git show` for each commit I've authored, but I need the command to only show the lines of code added, not the lines of code removed or the overview info that `git show` shows at the top.

(I'm not married to `git show`, maybe there's a better command, it's just the closest command I know.)

My best solution is to use `git log --author=<me>` and only get the commit shas (there's a command for this, I don't know it offhand). Then I can loop over the shas and do `git show -p <sha>`, but that gets me things I don't want (lines removed, and the overview). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git log -p` directly to get the patch inline with the log. Reducing the commit message with the `--oneline` option makes it easy to strip out. Then simply filter for the `+` lines of the patches, first filtering out the `+++` of the diff header and finally strip the leading `+`:

```
git log -p --oneline --author=<me> | grep -v '^+++ ' | grep '^+' | sed 's/^+//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe filter the output of git `show -p`:

```
git log --author="..." --format=format:%H \
  | xargs git show -p --dst-prefix=never-used-string/ \
  | sed -n '/never-used-string/! s/^+\(.*\)/\1/p'
```

should give you almost what you need (provided that `never-used-string` does not appear anywhere in your code).
Not sure about merge commits and the like...

Comment: Neat trick with the `--dst-prefix`. Note however that it will not work for deleted files. Those are always `+++ /dev/null` and won't have the `--dst-prefix` to filter them out. You could obviously additionally filter out `+++ /dev/null` itself.